# can't get the id using .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the tabs page... I am trying to get the id's of `li` from the loop and then hide it. the id's is not found.

```
<ul>
     <li id="Page1" class="tab"><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
     <li id="Page2" class="tab"><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery code:

```
   $(".tab").click(function() { 
       var thisclick = $(this).attr("id");
       var links = $(this).parent();
       $(links).each(function() {
           $("#PG_" + $(this).attr("id") ).hide();
       });
        $("#PG_" + thisclick).show();
   });
```

Comment: Some div's for example: `<div id='PG_Page2'> content here </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the `links` variable is a pointer to the `ul` element:

```
var links = $(this).parent();
```

change to this one may help you:

```
   $(".tab").click(function() { 
       var thisclick = $(this).attr("id");
       var links = $(this).parent();
       $(links).find("li").each(function() {
           $("PG_" + $(this).attr("id") ).hide();
       });
        $("PG_" + thisclick).show();
   });
```

Also, you can use

```
$(links).children("li").each( //etc
```

OR

```
$("li", links).each( //etc
```

Comment: Pretty close. I would be inclined to cache $(this) since it gets re-used a few times. And the variable "links" is already a jQuery object so you don't need to wrap it again. links.find(etc) will work. See also @jAndy's this.id point.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly you have some corresponding elements on the page that should be shown only if underlying link has been clicked. If that's the case then this would work:

```
$(".tab").click(function() {
   var thisclick = $(this).attr("id");
   var links = $(this).parent().children();
   $(links).each(function() {
       $("#PG_" + $(this).attr("id")).hide();
   });
    $("#PG_" + thisclick).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gdc88/4/

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, you want jQuery to query for a *Nodename* called `PG_Page1` for instance, which most likely, will have no result. Unless you got tags like

```
<PG_Page1></PG_Page2>
```

somewhere on your page. So my guess is, you either forgot the prefix the string with a `.` for a classname, or a `#` for an id.

And by the way, you can just access `this.id` instead creating a jQuery wrapper object and finally call `attr()` on it.

Comment: Although the original code has since been updated so that the "." or "#" advice is addressed, the this.id is still an important point for the original poster to take into consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Do you miss `#` in the selector?

```
$("#PG_" + $(this).attr("id") ).hide();
```

Comment: I realised that and fixed my question.. but  `$(this).attr("id")` does not work

Answer (score 0):

With a small `class` addition to your HTML, you can simplify your jQuery.  Like so

```
<ul>
    <li id="Page1" class="tab"><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
    <li id="Page2" class="tab"><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='PG_Page1' class="page"> content from page 1 here </div>

<div id='PG_Page2' class="page"> content from page 2 here </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".tab").click(function() {
    var thisclick = $(this).attr("id");
    $('div.page').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("#PG_" + thisclick).show();        
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/fZNUH/